# Help selecting technology for web app

Tags: flash, web-applications, browser, applet

I want to develop an app, which will have a GUI, and will do real time processing of user input. App should work in most common web browsers, and processing will be client side.  **Also, the app must only work if user is online and logged in to my website. 
Something like a "license"**.

People should not be able to hack/reverse engineer the code etc.

Is it possible to do what I want using Java Applet or a Flash application?  Any other technology?

Comment: this is not a discussion site.

Comment: I have re-framed the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can download same sources from the NET

Comment: Hmmm. I didn't get it. You mean that if I make a Java Applet or Flash application, people can see the code?